# Casting array pointer to another type gives different output for different compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, c

I was trying the `reinterpret_cast` in C++, but then I noticed an inconsistency with it. It gave different outputs for different optimization levels. Then I tried the C-version of it and it gave the wrong output again.

This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long* arr = (unsigned long long*)malloc(16);
    arr[0] = 0x300000061;
    arr[1] = 9;
    int* casted = (int*)(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", casted[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the `int* casted = (int*)(arr);` where it casts the pointer. When instead casting to char* and increasing 3 to 12 in the for-loop it gives the output I expect.

Output with O1-O3 flag:

```
0
0
0
```

Output without any O flag:

```
97
3
9
```

Output with char (with or without optimization):

```
97
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
9
0
0
0
```

The second output is what I would expect. Is this kind of pointer casting undefined behaviour or is it a compiler bug?

I use the WSL gcc compiler.

Edit:
Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to write an asm function to get the desired output? I know I could use memcpy() instead but I need to use this in a specific problem I can't explain easily, so I'd rather not.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is *undefined behavior* as you are violating strict aliasing rules

Comment: To get what you need reliably, you should `memcpy()` into `int[]` buffer. Or, in C++20, you can use `std::bit_cast<>`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in C only the `int *` variation has undefined behavior.  It is allowed to cast to `char *` and read out the representation of the data through that.

Comment: So there isn't a way without copying it? I just looked into the source code of std::bit_cast<> but that is also a memcpy()

Comment: Fun fact: A good C++ compiler will often see a `memcpy`, understand what you're doing with it, and then optimize out the `memcpy`, leaving you with effectively a cast, when it's safe to do so.

Comment: @SadsaProgrammer Yes, only `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` can alias other types to allow you to read and write their byte representation.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking to the C program presented:

> The second output is what I would expect. Is this kind of pointer casting undefined behaviour or is it a compiler bug?

The *casting* has well-defined behavior, but reading out the data via the resulting `int *` is a violation of the strict-aliasing rule (C17 paragraph 6.5/7).  That produces undefined behavior. On the other hand, it is allowed to read the representation of any object via a `char *`, so that variation is ok (at least in C).

Observable behavior changing at different optimization levels is one of the common symptoms of UB, and especially of UB arising from violation of the strict-aliasing rule.

As far as I am aware, similar applies to C++: you are allowed to use `reinterpret_cast` to convert `unsigned long long *` to `int *`, but UB results from attempting to derference the resulting pointer.

Comment: Is it also undefined behavior when writing to a casted (else than char) pointer?

Comment: That's more complicated, @SadsaProgrammer.  It's different when the object being written is dynamically allocated, as in the example, than it is in other cases.  In the dynamically allocated case, writing via the converted pointer is allowed, but it changes the "effective type" of the memory that is written, so that afterward reading it back via the original pointer would have UB.  When there is no dynamic allocation involved, data types are not subject to such changes, and writing via the converted pointer produces UB.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: writing via a converted-and-laundered pointer isn't UB in and of itself, but you're required to put back a value of the original data type before using the original variable name or any other alias not derived from the pointer used to do the write.  see https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8 and https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#9

Comment: @BenVoigt, I was speaking primarily in terms of C, since that's how the OP specified that the code presented should be interpreted, but I'm not immediately seeing any conflict with the C++ provisions you've linked.